# how to find dynamically created table on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i created dynamically a table with in a function... this table is added to a panel. and this panel is in ajax updatepanel... 
statically i have given no of rows as 3, for that table... in page_load my table with 3 rows is created.... but i cannot identify this table in another button click event...

i wrote the code like this...

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table table = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table)addrowpnl.FindControl("Table1");
```

here **Table1** is my dynamic table id.....

could anyone please suggest me to solve this

Comment: @oded... 
i didnt know what is the purpose of marking those answers...

Answer (score 0):

This is the so known problem of dynamically created objects in ASP.NET.

Read this to get a grasp of what I'm telling you:

[Accessing controls created dynamically (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982198/accessing-controls-created-dynamically-c/2982271#2982271)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with dynamically created buttons. What you should try is to create objects in Page_Init rather then in Page_Load. I know it is not always possible but it should be done there.