# Dynamic radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I get the selected value of a radioButtonList if this is created dynamically? I know that a dynamic control must be recreated on each postback but, is there a trick to solve this scenario?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You'd get a reference to your RadioButtonList after the postback and would get the value the same way you'd get if it was created statically.

Take a look here:

[Accessing controls created dynamically (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982198/accessing-controls-created-dynamically-c/2982271#2982271) (take a look at the question to see how to get a reference to the dynamically created control)

It just happens that the above answer has a RadioButtonList example.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're creating the listitems in Page_Init - not Page_Load.  The Viewstate will be hooked up correctly and you should be able to get the SelectedValue as normal.

(Also, if your RBL is in a usercontrol, that any values/objects needed for the RBL are loaded in that Init as well, that's what fooled me for a long itme.)