# Dynamic adding elements in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, postback

Look at this code:

```
        static int i = 0;
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlButton myButton;
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            myButton = new HtmlButton();
            myButton.InnerText = "Button first load";
            myButton.ID = i.ToString();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myButton);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            myButton = new HtmlButton();
            myButton.InnerText = "Button postback" + i.ToString();
            myButton.ID = i.ToString();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myButton);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

expected:

```
       first load:  "Button first load"
       first postback: first load + "Button postback1"
       second postback: first postback + "Button postback2" ... and so on.
```

have:

```
      "Button first load"
      "Button postback1"
      "Button postback2".
```

Why?

Comment: How do you expect the button `InnerText` to contain the string `first load + Button postback1` or `first postback + Button postback2` if you don't even have them in your code?

Comment: I expect new button elements on the form.

Comment: You have them or am I wrong? You say you have: 3 buttons namely: `"Button first load"`, `"Button postback1"`and `"Button postback2"`.

Comment: When page loads first i have only one button -[ "Button first load"].after first postback I expect have two buttons [ "Button first load"] + [ "Button postback1"],third - three buttons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected results are really wrong... :)

Right now what's happening is exactly what you have written in the code:

1st load (not postback):

```
 myButton.InnerText = "Button first load";
```

Then:

```
"Button first load"
```

2nd, 3rd, nth load (postback):

```
 myButton.InnerText = "Button postback" + i.ToString();
```

Then:

```
"Button postback1"
"Button postback2"
.
.
.
```

---

UPDATE:

Now that I understood your problem...

ASP.NET does not persist state of dynamic controls and thus cannot recreate them after the postback.

Bottom line: ***You must recreate your dynamically added controls after each postback.***

Here's an answer I gave more than 2 years ago that shows you a nice way of handling such situation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2982271/114029

Comment: but every time this is reference to new object -  myButton = new HtmlButton();